# Transparent Object as clipPath

Tags: fabricjs

I'm using `clipPath` on an object so that it can only be seen inside of a `fabric.Rect`, as seen [here](http://fabricjs.com/clippath-part4) . In order to see my background image, I set my rect fill to `'transparent'`.

For clarity, I also added a red stroke.

```
const clipRectangle = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 0,
  top : 0,
  absolutePositioned: true,
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  fill: 'transparent',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  stroke: 'red',
  selectable: false,
})
```

And then setting it as clipPath for my image:

```
      img.set({
        left: clipRectangle.left + (clipRectangle.width / 2),
        top: clipRectangle.top + (clipRectangle.height / 2),
        centeredScaling: true,
        lockScalingFlip: true,
        selectable: true,
        clipPath: clipRectangle,
      })
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following: if you look closely at the bottom right side of my rectangle stroke, the clipped image is only visible on the stroke: it seems like the transparency is also applied to the content of the clip path.

Is there a way to make the content visible, while keeping the rectangle transparent ?

[image: Partial image]

Comment: post your code. we can't tell what you are doing. Does your clipPath shape have a fill?

Comment: @NoGrabbing done, I added the code for both my clipPath and my image

Comment: @PierreOlivierTran I'm also facing the same issue, how did you manage to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered setting the opacity value rather than setting fill to transparent?
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#opacity

Answer (score 0):

**Change the opacity in the clipping object**

Objects in fabric js have an opacity property:
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#opacity

If you set it to a value close to zero it will have the result that you're looking for. For example:

```
var clipRectangle = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  width: 250,
  height: 200,
  fill: '#ff0000',
  opacity: 0.01,
  absolutePositioned: true
});
```

I've made a **jsfiddle demonstrating this effect:**
http://jsfiddle.net/hsyL7tpr/1/